# Android Internet Connection Broadcast Recevier

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My app is running in the background (as a Service) and needs to be connected to a remote server all the time to receive and send messages.

This Service runs a Thread which manage the connection to the server (with Socket)

i'm trying to write an internet connection Broadcast Receiver which will run every time the internet state is changed and check if the state is connected of disconnected.

my problem is as follow: when i'm connected to Wi-Fi network the Broadcast Receiver Intent is fired few times which in all of them the state of the internet connection is true (with no disconnection between every fire, which means i have few new Threads using the Socket to connect the server.

How can i make sure i'm getting the state of the internet right, and by right i mean that the .isConnected() method will return if and only if the connection is connected ?

this is my code:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{       
    action = intent.getAction();
    app = (AppVariables) context.getApplicationContext();       
    if (app.isApplicationInitilized())
    {   
        if (action.equals(action.equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)))
        {
            networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            if (networkInfo.isConnected())
                app.getServerConnectionManager().startServer();
        }
        else if(action.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION))
        {
            networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);                
            if(networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI && !networkInfo.isConnected())
                app.getServerConnectionManager().stopServer(false);
            else if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE && !networkInfo.isConnected())
                app.getServerConnectionManager().stopServer(false);
            else
                app.getServerConnectionManager().startServer();
        }           
    }       
}
```

Comment: what is the action that you are using please let me know. I need to use too. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue for one of my apps, and the pattern we deployed (successfully) is as follows:

```
onReceive():
   if( networkInfo.isConnected() ) 
       fireTimerForSecondaryCheck();
   else
       not connected;

SecondaryCheck:
     if( loadKnownUrl() )
          is connected.
          fire long timer for secondary check
     else
          fire short timer for secondary check
```

Basically what this does is attempt to access the internet once the network manager reports that wifi is up. If it receives the expected content, then the network connection is up and working, and I'll check again in two minutes. If I don't receive the expected content, it means either the network connection is not fully up, can't connect to the internet, or the wifi might have a landing page for TOS or similar. In that case, I check again in 10 seconds.

FWIW, my NetworkMonitorService broadcasts connectivity to my app, which registers for it, and updates the UI as necessary.

This was developed in 2.3.3, and I believe the newer Android versions (4+) have finer granularity in the network state, but I haven't seen the need to adjust this code yet in production. It works well from 2.2 devices all the way to 4.2.

Comment: but when connected to wifi to code you wrote will run as many times as the broadcast fire. lets say it fire 4 times - 4 receivers will lunch. how do u know which one of the receiver should create a new connection to the server? 
BTW, do you know what causing this ? maybe it will help to understand what's happening under the hood

Comment: I register mine as follows: `this.registerReceiver( this.myWifiReceiver, new IntentFilter( ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION ) );` and I'm pretty certain I only get one fire per wifi state transition.

Comment: Just verified -- using the broadcast receiver as registered in my previous comment fires the onReceive only ONCE per wifi transition. (Gtab2/7", Android 4.0.3, it was nearest my laptop).

Comment: you might be right on Android 4.0.3 but in 2.3.3 it fires it 3-4 times when connecting to wifi network - which is exectly my problem..

Comment: Checked again against my 2.3.4 device (Kindle Fire). Only fires once.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to know the state of connection.
You can obtain that by using networkInfo state:

State state = networkInfo.getState();

if (state == State.CONNECTED) do_something